# HTMl over XML to jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have my XML file generated, with one line looking like this, including html;

```
<status><span class='rejected'>Rejected</span></status>
```

Now in my Ajax request i have this line to pull contents;

```
var status = $offer.find("status").text();
```

Which works fine, but only pulls the text Rejected from the XML.

Im guessing this is to do with the text() part?

How can i pull all the html?

EDITED:

```
    $(data).find('notification').each(function(){  

        var $notification = $(this);
        var message = $notification.find("message").html();

        notificationhtml += '<li>'+ message + '</li>' ;
```

Thats the jquery i have, for anouther function it does work ok, i have outputted the XML to console and everything is fine there. But as you can see above i have changed .text() to .html(), but this just shows nothing instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

`.text()` extract only the text without all the HTML code.
`.html()` extract all the code, like `.innerHTML`.

I made a quick [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/JNVKV/) showing the differences.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code you use please ? And the xml.

Comment: If you log $notification, has it the correct content ?
Idem for message.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean :/
however it is picking up the correct part of the XML, because if i change it to text, it displays my error text. its just missing out the html

Comment: Add console.log($notification) after its definition.
Idem for message.  And see the result in firebug.  Or use alert().

Comment: Did that, with html, it does do anything, and shows nothing in the alert :/

Comment: So jQuery don't find the <notification> tag.
Can you display your xml please ?